# Fetch recurrence calendar event in ios

Tags: ios, ekevent

I can able to fetch calendar events for a day but what if I want to know next recurrence event?

Ex: There is a calendar event which is recursive i.es weekdays.
Now when given a single date I will get many calendar event ,In that lets assume there is an event which is recursive, now I would require all the next calendar events related to that.

i.es If there is a calendar event on 13th which is Friday then the next event will be on Monday i.es 16th then then next 17th ...

So I would like to know next 5 events of a recursive event.

Please let me know if you require more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible only by EkRecurrenceRule, read the properties and calculate the next event.